# Libaums - Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/fipstimakeystore.jar'

Tags: android, usb

I'm using libaums on Android to write files to USB stick. Everything works fine but at app startup I get a load of errors in logcat, triggered by FileSystemFactory.registerFileSystem:

```
public class CopyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    static {
-->     FileSystemFactory.registerFileSystem(new JavaFsFileSystemCreator());
    }
```

[...]

The gist of the logcat is in these lines:

```
02-18 16:22:09.318 23778-23778/com.tmpsystems.chipandship I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-18 16:22:09.518 23778-23778/com.tmpsystems.chipandship I/System.out: debugger has settled (1341)
02-18 16:22:09.528 23778-23778/com.tmpsystems.chipandship D/ContextImpl: ContextImpl running for user UserHandle{0} 0
02-18 16:22:09.748 23778-23778/com.tmpsystems.chipandship W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/fipstimakeystore.jar': I/O Error
[...]
Unable to open '/system/framework/fipstimakeystore.jar': No such file or directory
[...]
02-18 16:22:09.868 23778-23778/com.tmpsystems.chipandship W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /jacoco.exec: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
[...]
02-18 16:22:09.878 23778-23778/com.tmpsystems.chipandship W/System.err:     at com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.FileSystemFactory.registerFileSystem(FileSystemFactory.java)
02-18 16:22:09.878 23778-23778/com.tmpsystems.chipandship W/System.err:     at com.tmpsystems.chipandship.CopyActivity.<clinit>(CopyActivity.java:44)
```

This does not seem to affect copying to USB stick which works ok, but I'd still like to understand what's it about.

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty weird. I do not really know what it is and what could be causing this. It looks pretty much unrelated to libaums although the exception says otherwise.

JaCoCo is a tool I use to create the code coverage stats for codecov. But I do not know why this would interfere if you debug/launch the app. Do you get that if you are running the example file manager as well? Can you maybe try again after removing the JaCoCo stuff:

https://github.com/magnusja/libaums/blob/acbd724223a91d392d98aa053ca5d5ab39783161/libaums/build.gradle#L2

https://github.com/magnusja/libaums/blob/a9fe9e54e6271577430537bd71f0784b77c9e229/build.gradle#L15

Comment: I've removed jacoco references from local libaums build

Comment: But the problem persists. Then in javafs gradle I've changed 
"compile 'com.github.mjdev:libaums:0.5.5'" to 
"compile project(':libaums')". 
This results in "javafs\src\main\java\com\github\magnusja\libaums\javafs\wrapper\fs\FileSystemWrapper.java
Error:(17, 8) error: FileSystemWrapper is not abstract and does not override abstract method getType() in FileSystem

Comment: More info on Gitter, can't fit logcat into comments.